# Why $d(x,Y)>0$ in proof of Riesz's lemma

Tags: general-topology

I'm reading through a proof of Riesz's lemma (below), and I cannot understand one of the steps.

Riesz's lemma states:

Let $X$ be a Banach space. Let $Y \subsetneq X$ be a closed subspace of $X$. Then there exists an $x_0 \in X\setminus Y$ such that $d(x_0,Y):=\inf\big\{||x_0-y|| \mid y \in Y\big\}>\frac{1}{2}$

In the proof, it states: Let us choose some $x\in X\setminus Y$. Then $d(x,Y)>0$. Why is this true? Supposedly it derives from the fact that it's closed (or a closed subspace) somehow, but I cannot see how to prove this myself.

Any ideas?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Yes, since Y is closed, its complement is open, hence all points in the complement are interior points (they can be isolated by epsilon balls).

Comment: I believe you want to say "choose some $x\in X\setminus Y$" instead of "choose some $x\in X$."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Let $X$ be a Banach space, of which $Y\subset X$ is a proper closed subspace. Then, for all $x\in X\setminus Y$, $$d(x,Y) > 0$$

Since $Y \subsetneq X$ is closed, $X\setminus Y$ is open (in the metric topology induced by the norm on $X$.) Choose any $x\in X\setminus Y$. There exists some $\varepsilon >0$ such that $B(x,\varepsilon) \subset X\setminus Y$, i.e.,
$$B(x,\varepsilon ) \cap Y = \varnothing$$
With that in mind, we have
$$\|x-y\| \ge \varepsilon$$ for any $y\in Y$. Taking the infimum over all $y\in Y$, we have
$$d(x,Y) = \inf\{\|x-y\|: y\in Y\} \ge \varepsilon > 0$$
as required.